# How big was the F-14 fleet compared to other US carrier-based aircraft in 1981?

Tags: military, aviation-history, usa, aircraft-carrier, f-14

Back in the 80's I was away jesting about the F-14 are here to protect the carriers and the carriers to deploy F-14.

I know there are a number of other aircraft here for other purposes but I really don't know the numbers.

So for 1981 what's the proportion of F-14 to other aircrafts and also de percentuals in roles (defence of the fleet, attack, surveillance, etc).

In other words: for US aircraft carriers of that period, what was the aircraft fleet composition?

Comment: Which ship or which class of ships are we talking about here?

Comment: @user3528438 All US aircraft carriers ships in service in 1981? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aircraft_carriers_of_the_United_States_Navy

Comment: This might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_air_wing#Cold_War_(1974%E2%80%931990)_and_the_1983_Invasion_of_Grenada

Comment: F-14s were aboard all large deck carriers, except for the Midway class ships and the training carrier Lexington.

Comment: Are you asking about the Embarked Airwing, or about F-14's?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Embarked airwing and F-14 role and numbers comparation with the other aircraft here

Comment: Your bottom line question and your title question don't match; why don't you rephrase your title to match your bottom line question?

Answer (score 6):

During the plane’s heyday, the US Navy maintained 26 active duty F-14 squadrons for the 12 carriers certified for F-14 operations, 4 Test and Evaluation squadrons, 2 Fleet Replacement squadrons and 4 Naval Reserve squadrons.  632 F-14s were delivered to the US Navy between 1973 and 1994.  Each Forrestal-, Kitty Hawk-, Enterprise-, Kennedy-, and Nimitz-Class carrier had two squadrons of F-14s aboard, with 12 aircraft per squadron.  Depending on the cruise air wings aboard, there were approx 85 aircraft aboard ship.  This sets the F-14s comprising about 28% of the air wing’s airframes.

The F-14 was used to provide air superiority in the airspace around the battlegroup as well as escorting strike packages and providing a first line of defense against long range enemy interceptors and cruise missiles.  Later upgrades as well as the F-14D variant allow for precision strike capability against surface targets as well.  The genesis of the AWG-9/AIM-54 weapons system was as a defense against TU-22s carrying Kitchen cruise missiles which had a very real chance of sinking a carrier if the missile found its mark.  A secondary role was given to the F-14 in the early 80s as the primary tactical reconnaissance aircraft for the fleet, replacing the aging RA-5C Vigilante and RF-8 Crusader aircraft by means of a removable Tactical Aerial Reconnisance Pod System (TARPS) which mounted on the center body pylons for the AIM-54 missile.  Later systems included ROVER pods for precision close air support.

Comment: Not doubting you, but some sources would turn an good answer into a great one. Also, the "TARPS which ovule Mount"... care to fix a typo or two there?

Comment: This also doesn't show how these numbers compared to the total naval air fleet.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grumman_F-14_Tomcat

Comment: Also Robinson, Anthony, US Air Power.